# Avoiding temporary variables when returning vectors from two or more functions

Tags: c++, c++11, rvo

I wonder if there is any way to avoid extra copies when returning std::vector's by a function and "creating" their values directly in vector "integers". The most usual way of doing so before c++11 was passing main std::vector by reference (&) and use it within the filling functions, but I would like to avoid that approach and try something more modern c++ way.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> function1()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.emplace_back(1);
    v.emplace_back(2);
    v.emplace_back(3);
    
    return v;
}

std::vector<int> function2()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.emplace_back(10);
    v.emplace_back(11);
    
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> integers;
    
    const auto v1 = function1();
    std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(integers));
    
    const auto v2 = function2();
    std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::back_inserter(integers));
    
    return 0;
}
```

What I want is to create directly the elements in the vector defined in main, if possible using c++11 or above features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compilers are likely to do NRVO, and place the contents of the vector directly where needed. (This isn't required though). You should look at the assembly to see what's happening.

Comment: RVO will most likely happen in your case, and the copying will be elided. Just like you seem to want. Please be more specific about the problem with the code shown.

Comment: Do you mean to avoid creating temporary `v1` and `v2` sub-vectors or do you only care that `v1` and `v2` are constructed without copying?

Comment: What is bad about passing by ref? You don't need to use modern things only because they are more modern.

Comment: I am sure that v1 anf v2 should be generated without copying in any modern compiler, but I wonder if it is posible to avoid temporary v1 and v2 vector and creating directly over integers vector. i am not an expert in profiling neither assembly, and know I wonder if maybe I was wrong and this code is doing already that. Someone may help me with this?

Comment: @Thrasher: I totally agree with you in that point, but sometimes modern c++ is more expressive than older ways. Also, I like to learn about new c++ features from people who knows more than me

Comment: @Pablo why you want to avoid declare `v1` and `v2`?

Comment: and by your comment you don't put the title correct?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to avoid the `v1` and `v2` variables, and be able to use e.g. `function1()` directly in the call to `std::copy`? Using plain C++11 it's not possible. It's probably possible to insert directly into `integers` using [C++20 ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges). And also probably possible to do in older variants using [the ranges-v3 library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

Comment: N/RVO can only make a function use a vector that is just now starting its lifetime. To use older vector, there is only one way, and that is to pass a reference/pointer. Anything else in modern C++ is just going to be a sugar coat over that.

Comment: `ranges::join`/`ranges::concat` would allow to have a lazy range from existing `v1`, `v2`. we might expect similar things with co_routine generator (C++20 ++) to create vector/generator from several generators (to avoid `v1`/`v2`)...

Answer (score 0):

If you write your functions like this:

```
std::vector<int> function1()
{
    return std::vector<int> {1, 2, 3};
}

std::vector<int> function2()
{
    return std::vector<int> {10, 11};
}
```

then from c++17, RVO is mandatory, and the vectors will be constructed directly at the call site.

---

From c++20, you can avoid creating the vector in `main` at all, by doing:

```
std::ranges::copy(function1(), std::back_inserter(integers));
std::ranges::copy(function2(), std::back_inserter(integers));
```

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it seems the actual question (from comments) is (what I thought) "*I wonder if it is posible to avoid temporary v1 and v2 vector and creating directly over integers vector*".

Comment: @cigien Neither I am the downvoter, thank you for trying to help me! I have upvoted you for teaching me about ranges, but I can not use c++20 features due to a constraint, so I guess I am not able to do this unless using a third party lib as ranges-v3, which is a not affordable overwork for my project.

Comment: @Pablo No problem, happy to help :) Even if you can't use it now, you know what to use later :)